# Select all checkboxes by selecting another one

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side, checkbox

Hello guys i'm starting with jquery and I got a problem when i try to select all check boxes in a page by clicking in another check box.

this is my Jquery code:

```
$('.selecionarTodos').live('click', function () {

        alert("test");

        var checkbox = $(this).children('td').children('[type="checkbox"]');

        $('.headerChkItem').each(function () {

            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                $(this).css('background-color', '');
                checkbox.attr('checked', false);
                $(this).children('td').children('[id*="hfSelecionada"]').val('false');
                qtdTotal = qtdTotal - parseFloat($(this).children('.quantidade').text().replace(',', '.'));
            }
            else {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#e8f783');
                checkbox.attr('checked', true);
                $(this).children('td').children('[id*="hfSelecionada"]').val('true');
                qtdTotal = qtdTotal + parseFloat($(this).children('.quantidade').text().replace(',', '.'));
            }

        });
    });
```

and this is my client side code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selecionar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <HeaderTemplate>
   <input type="checkbox" id="headerChkItem" cssclass="selecionarTodos" runat="server" />
     </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkItem" disabled="disabled" cssclass="selecionado" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

PS.: that "alert" in Jquery is not running when i test.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it from an `id="headerChkItem"` to `class="headerChkItem"`
Also - is `"cssclass"` part of the server-side language?  Or should that be `"class"`?

Comment: ok, i've changed cssclass, to class, and it was executed, but now I still have to select all itens by clicking at this checkbox, I must to loop in all my grid lines?

Comment: Can you post the HTML on the client-side, rather than the server-side code above?  I can't see where the <td> tags are, etc.  Also - did you change the id to a class?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your server code (from your example) looks something like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="DataSource" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="WebApplication1.Test"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid" DataSourceID="DataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selecionar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <input type="checkbox" class="selecionarTodos headerChkItem" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="selecionado chkItem" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and for this grid you will need something like this:

```
$('.selecionarTodos').on('click', function () {
        var gridCheckboxes = $(this).parents('table').find('input:checkbox.chkItem');
        var qtdTotal = 0;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
            gridCheckboxes.attr('checked', true);
            qtdTotal = qtdTotal - parseFloat($(this).children('.quantidade').text().replace(',', '.'));
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#e8f783');
            gridCheckboxes.attr('checked', false);
            qtdTotal = qtdTotal + parseFloat($(this).children('.quantidade').text().replace(',', '.'));
        }
    });
```

Your errors was mostly:

- using cssclass attribute when class is the right one
- wrong selection of checkboxes in table

I still don't understand why you use for each loop for all header checkboxes. Code i posted just sits on header checkbox and when you click on it all other checkboxes in grid will be checked or unchecked base on header checkbox state.